# Joomla is already up to date - but I never updated it

Tags: update, one-click-updates

I have a joomla! site installed in the root of my website and (it's a long story I can't solve right now) some other joomla! sites installed each in its own subfolder.

I upgraded joomla! to the latest version (3.7.0) on the root site, and for some reason the sites in the subfolders don't ask me for the upgrade, as if it had already been done.

Has it really already been done when I upgraded the site at the upper level? (This would work if there was some sort of plugin that looks for all instances of everything to be changed and updates them - this would not work if it looked in the proper paths and so only things outside the custom subfolders with my other sites really got touched)

Or is it just that something at the upper level acts as a flag and the sites in the subfolders just "think" that the upgrade has already been done?

What should I do to ensure that all subfoldered sites get properly updated (until I finally get to remove that joomla! install from the upper folder)?

Comment: Joomla doesn't update any sites in subdirectories. Try clearing your Joomla cache and check for updates again.

Comment: @Lodder yet when clicking on "Joomla is already up to date" it tells me I have 3.7.0 on subfolder sites, even after clearing both Joomla caches on every site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if your shared hosting provider auto-updates via Softaculous or whatever they provide for their apps installer. Many do, and yours may have that as the default setting.

Either that or maybe you have an extension installed like Auto-Update for Joomla.

Each Joomla install updates separately, and these are both options for automatically updating your sites.

Comment: That was it. For some reason, the root site was not even listed in the subdirectories of the autoupdater of my hosting provider.